# Angularjs destroy is not working

Tags: angularjs, destroy

http://plnkr.co/edit/UfQJU661pQR0DMY3c61t?p=preview

I got above code from AngularJs site and only thing I have added a button to delete a Div where we have controller but after delete no destroy method called as I have put alert in Directive and Controller.

```
element.on('$destroy', function() {
alert('destroy directive interval');
$interval.cancel(stopTime);
});
```

and

```
 $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
alert('destroy controller interval');
// Make sure that the interval is destroyed too
$scope.stopFight();
});
```

please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The main thing to be noticed

When `element.remove()` is executed that element and all of its children will be removed from the DOM together will all event handlers attached via for example element.on.

It will not destroy the $scope associated with the element.

So you need to manually trigger scope.$destroy();

First get the scope of element:-

```
 var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("mainDiv")).scope();
```

Second remove the element from dom:-

```
$('#mainDiv').remove();
```

Third destroy scope manually:-

```
 scope.$destroy();
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xJfRgM7W4CvaR2YYVpKr?p=info)

Comment: @mohamedrias not exactly firstly i explained why it is not triggering the destroy event because element.remove() destroy all the events including 'on' event that's why it is not triggering the destroy event.Then i explained your answer line by line :-P Thanks :)

Comment: So it is a Bug.   As when angular know the element where we are adding controller and directive so it can add DOM remove event.

Comment: No not a bug it's not possible (or may be possible i am not sure) for angular to listen all the dom remove events :)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it outside of angular's context.

```
<button id="btn" onclick="DeleteMainDiv()">DeleteDiv</button>
```

So in your `DeleteMainDiv()` function

```
 function DeleteMainDiv() {
      alert('Controller div going to remove');
      //debugger;
      var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("mainDiv")).scope();
      $('#mainDiv').remove();
      scope.$destroy();
    }
```

This will trigger the destroy functionality.

But I don't see a need of it. Angular will automatically run the `$destroy` event handler when the route changes or directive no longer required.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/FLDeF9bKAtnZyCFpA1T6?p=preview)**

Comment: Do you not think? Angular should add watcher behind the scene as Angular know what is the element where we are adding controller or directive.

Comment: It would become very hectic to keep track of all DOM elements. Already many debate about angular's $digest cycle as its reducing the performance of angular. That's the reason in Angular 2.0, they are rewriting the digest cycle completely with ES6 observe property. If angular has to keep track of all DOM $destroy events then it would be a performance hit. But it does when the route changes. In your case, you've manually removed the DOM elements so it's not aware of it as the scope is still valid.